# .net core in visual studio works with console app but not with wpf or winforms

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I've downloaded visual studio community 2019
version 16.0.0 but wpf and winforms with .net core says this `To create this project type, go to Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | .NET Core and check "Use Preview versions of the .NET Core SDK"`
I have checked it and restarted multiple times but that error  message persists

What should I do.

Comment: .Net Core Winforms designer is available from 16.6. You can refer to this blog [Windows Forms Designer for .NET Core Released](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/windows-forms-designer-for-net-core-released/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 16.0.0

Update to 16.7.2. Core 3.1 is not in preview and has not been since late 2019, but some of that support followed the initial release of VS 2018.

Also ensure you have installed the correct workload with the installer (.NET Desktop Development).